# Access mariadb SQL outside of docker python

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, docker

I have a problem, I got a docker running on 190 with mariadb database

I have an other nodejs server inside a container running on 191 that can access the database

I have a last container that run on 192 but when i want to connect to database I got a `KeyError: 'timeout'`.

The question that i have is why nodeJS can access and not python

```
# Python connect
cnxn = mariadb.connect(
    user=sql_logs["username"],
    password=sql_logs["password"],
    host=sql_logs["address"],
    port=sql_logs["port"],
    database=sql_logs["database"]
)
```

```
// NodeJS connect
connection = mysql.createConnection(sql_security_logs);
```

Comment: Do you run these container with a docker-compose or do you run them with docker run? 

Maybe mariadb's and nodejs' container are in the same network and python's container is inside another network

Comment: Hello, i do it with docker run :
There is the command : docker run -d --name dockername-p 192:80 pythondocker

Comment: Try to put all container inside same network or use a docker-compose, it will generate 3 services connected inside a common default network

Comment: The question is that my database could be in an other place in the network, is there a way tu put my docker on my server network

Comment: you can connect any container with any number of docker networks.
inside containers the host of pointed container will be "nameOfContainer:port" if you want point the container from your local machine will be "localhost:portexposed"
I hope this can help you :)

Comment: What do you mean by "on 190", "on 191", and "on 192"? Are those supposed to be parts of IP addresses?

Comment: The only port mapping you should need is `3306:3306`, but only if you run your sql clients on your host. Otherwise, you would link the containers using [Docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and you then don't need any port mappings to your host.